# Is it possible to chat with a Facebook group using a desktop app on macOS?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, messages, facebook

I would like to chat with my groups on Facebook using a desktop app.

So far I've tried:

1. [Adium](https://www.adium.im/), it is quite nice, but it doesn't support group conversations.
2. Native Messages app doesn't seem to support the Facebook group chat as well.

Is there any way to configure these or any other free applications so that I can chat on my group conversation?

I'm looking for any solution. I'd prefer to use Messages.app but if it is not possible, I'd like to know if there is any other app that can handle group conversations from Facebook.

Comment: Your title and body seem contradictory on what you're looking for in an answer? Are you looking for a [tag:software-recommendation] (which the body would suggest but you haven't tagged as such) for software that will allow this, or software that will integrate Facebook group chat with Messages.app, or just a first-party solution in OS X?

Comment: @grgarside, I'm looking for any solution. I'd prefer to use Messages.app but if it is not possible, I'd like to know if there is any other app that can handle group conversations from Facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Goofy app](http://www.goofyapp.com) is an awesome solution. The app is a simple wrapper of the messenger.com website.

I really enjoy using it. This is what I was looking for.

The source code is available here on GitHub: https://github.com/danielbuechele/goofy.

Answer (score 2):

I have not used it, but [Current for Facebook](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/current-for-facebook/id923920635?mt=12) claims to support group chats.

Comment: To be fair, it's $3.

Answer (score 1):

Messenger for Facebook does it.  Its an application in the Appstore.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/messenger-for-facebook-chat/id1009179228?mt=12

Comment: This app is no longer available.